# Using turkish character package distorts frame structure in beamer

Tags: beamer, turkish

I have a problem with beamer frames. I noticed there are some characters (letters) showing up at the bottom of the frame. I made some trials to remove packages and understand which package created the problem and found that the packages I used for Turkish characters create the problem. How can I overcome this problem?

Thank you

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel} %Türkçe bölüm isimleri
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Türkçe karakterler
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Türkçe heceleme

\begin{document}
\title{XXXXX}  
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today} 

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 


\section{Section no.1} 
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title} 
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\begin{frame} 
Without title somethink is missing. 
\end{frame}
\section{Section no. 2} 
\subsection{Lists I}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you mean, in the case of the example you provide, the `XXXXX` and the `XYZ` that appear in the black and blue lines at the bottom, just use `\title[]{XXXXX}` and `\author[]{XYZ}`. However, this is the normal behavior of beamer to add the title and the author at the bottom of the frame or the shorttitle and shortauthor specified between brackets after `\title` and `\author`.

Comment: How can I remove title? Is it possible?

Comment: I figured it out thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

turkish makes the : an active char (a shorthand) and tikz doesn't like this. You can either disable the short hand or try the babel library of tikz.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel} %Türkçe bölüm isimleri
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Türkçe karakterler
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Türkçe heceleme
%\shorthandoff{:} %or this
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{XXXXX}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Section no.1}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
Each frame should have a title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\begin{frame}
Without title somethink is missing.
\end{frame}
\section{Section no. 2}
\subsection{Lists I}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I decided to move footnote area. Thank you very much!